# Boom chakka wah wah

Tags: history

'Boom chukka wah wah' has become a euphemism for sexual activity in recent years, I believe it references porn film sound tracks. What is the earliest reference of usage?

Comment: Hi Sehguh Nai!  Please provide your research when asking a question.  You can take the site tour for helpful information on how to use this site. http://english.stackexchange.com/tour  :-)

Answer (score 2):

From Wikipedia-

> Jordan Brady was also a professional stand-up comic in the 1980s. He was the originator of the line, "Bow Chicka Bow Wow!". ...his fresh and unique material ranged from impressions of G.I. Joe to re-enactments of entire porn film soundtracks.

Comment: You can watch Jordan Brady's skit featuring his reference to "Bow Chicka Bow Wow!" on the Comedy Central website: ["Porno" by Jordan Brady, posted 02/24/1992](http://www.cc.com/video-clips/9w1tvk/stand-up-jordan-brady--porno) (Potentially NSFW)